# How to add active class to one dynamically loaded element at a time (react)

Tags: jquery, reactjs, dynamic

So I am currently working on a receptionist website for a doctor's office. On my page, the doctor cards have been loaded dynamically. I would like to show the relevant information for that doctor when they are clicked but I first want to be able to show the card of the clicked doctor changing colour. I have managed to add an active class, however, multiple cards are able to have the active class at once - so this is what I would like to fix.

My code is as follows:

```
const VetItem = (props) => {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

  const showVetInfo = (event) => {
    event.currentTarget.classList.toggle('bg-salmon');
  };

  //show specific doctors

  const user = sessionStorage.getItem('activeUser');

  const [userId, setUserId] = useState({
    activeUser: sessionStorage.getItem('activeUser'),
  });

  const [renderActiveVet, setRenderActiveVet] = useState();
  const [activeVet, setActiveVet] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .post('http://localhost:80/project-api/readActiveDoctor.php', userId)
      .then((res) => {
        let data = res.data;
        let renderActiveVet = data.map((item) => (
          <Doctors
            key={item.id}
            rerender={setRenderActiveVet}
            uniqueId={item.id}
            name={item.name}
            surname={item.surname}
            specialization={item.specialization}
            age={item.age}
            gender={item.gender}
            email={item.email}
            contact={item.phoneNumber}
            doctorId={item.doctorId}
            room={item.room}
          />
        ));
        console.log(data);
        setActiveVet(renderActiveVet);
        setRenderActiveVet(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, [renderActiveVet]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={showVetInfo}
        className='individual-vet'
        id={props.uniqueId}
      >
        <div className='vet-block-img'>
          {' '}
          <img className='profileImg vet' src={dp} />
        </div>
        <div className='vet-block-text'>
          <h2>Dr. {props.name + ' ' + props.surname}</h2>
          <h4>{props.specialization}</h4>
        </div>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default VetItem;
```

This is the vetItem react component which will be outputted on the doctors page.

Comment: Where are you displaying the `<Doctors/>` component?

Comment: Thats currently an issue i'm sorting out but that should be displayed on the doctors page. I'm considering adding the component into the doctors page and passing the values through props.

Comment: so the active class should be inside `Doctors` component? what is the code of this component. i'm quite confused

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you want something like this. Each doctor has its own active state. clicked one toggles the css.

```
function DoctorList() {
  const [doctorsData, setDoctorsData] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    axios('fetchDoctorsData').then((data) => {
      setDoctorsData(data)
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      {doctorsData.map((doctorData) => (
        <DoctorCard key={doctorData.id} doctorData={doctorData} />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

function DoctorCard({ doctorData }) {
  const [isCardActive, setIsCardActive] = useState(false)

  const toggleActiveClass = () => {
    setIsCardActive((prev) => !prev)
  }

  return (
    <div
      className={`doctor-card${isCardActive ? ' bg-salmon' : ''}`}
      onClick={toggleActiveClass}
    ></div>
  )
}
```