# How to pass data received from a database as props to another component in react

Tags: reactjs, components, react-props

I am currently trying to send the data from my database to another component. The data is successfully showing in console.log, however, it is not showing on my component.

I know I am somehow passing the props incorrectly but not sure how.

My code is as follows:

```
    const showVetInfo = (event) => {
    event.currentTarget.classList.toggle('bg-salmon');
 
    let id = (event.currentTarget.id);
    console.log(id);

    axios.post('http://localhost:80/project-api/readActiveDoctor.php',userId )
    .then((res)=>{
      let data = res.data;
     let info =(data.map((item) =>  <DoctorInfo key={item.id} rerender={setRenderActiveVet} uniqueId={item.id} name={item.name} surname={item.surname} specialization={item.specialization} age={item.age} gender={item.gender} email={item.email} contact={item.phoneNumber} doctorId={item.doctorId} room={item.room} />)) 
  
       console.log(data);
    //   setActiveVet(renderActiveVet);
    //   setRenderActiveVet(false);
  
    })
    .catch(err=>{
      console.log(err);
    });


}




    return (
        <div>
          
             <button  onClick={showVetInfo}  className='individual-vet' id={props.uniqueId}   >
                     <div className='vet-block-img'>  <img className='profileImg vet' src={dp}/></div>
                     <div className='vet-block-text'>
                         <h2>Dr. {props.name + " " + props.surname}</h2>
                         <h4>{props.specialization}</h4>
                     </div>
                </button>
            
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Change onClick event to : `onClick={showVetInfo()}`

Comment: That breaks my code, because it impacts the event.

Comment: Correct approach would be to setState in showVetInfo function. Then access that state in return (///jsx). Do not create component inside that function.

Comment: How about `onClick={(e)=>{showVetInfo(e)}}`?

Comment: the problem is component structure isn't clear. Where is doctor info supposed to be?           @pizzajuice it is already an eventhandler no need to do that.

Comment: The doctorInfo is a separate component that is rendered on the doctor's page. So the rendering is happening but the passing of props is not working. If take the setState approach as mentioned above, the data displays but then it is in this component which is incorrect.

Comment: @AlexaPettitt I remember this code. I already have answered with an example how to store data and pass as a prop. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72711023/how-to-add-active-class-to-one-dynamically-loaded-element-at-a-time-react

Answer (score 2):

````
const showVetInfo = (event) => {
    event.currentTarget.classList.toggle('bg-salmon');
 
    let id = (event.currentTarget.id);
    console.log(id);

    axios.post('http://localhost:80/project-api/readActiveDoctor.php',userId )
    .then((res)=>{
      let data = res.data;
    
  //create a state and set data to it.
  setstate(data);

       console.log(data);
    //   setActiveVet(renderActiveVet);
    //   setRenderActiveVet(false);
  
    })
    .catch(err=>{
      console.log(err);
    });


}

//Now map your inside the return
//suppose this is your first component in this component you passing props to //second component.

return(
//your jsx (html) code

state.map((data,index)=><DoctorInfo key={index} name={data.name} surname={data.surname} specialization={data.specialization} />))

//you some jsx code
)










//this is second component
    return (
        <div>
          
             <button  onClick={showVetInfo}  className='individual-vet' id={props.uniqueId}   >
                     <div className='vet-block-img'>  <img className='profileImg vet' src={dp}/></div>
                     <div className='vet-block-text'>
                         <h2>Dr. {props.name + " " + props.surname}</h2>
                         <h4>{props.specialization}</h4>
                     </div>
                </button>
            
        </div>
    );
};```

**i hope you understand if you still have problems in understanding please comment below. 
Happy Coding :)**
````

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

```
export const showVetInfo = (event) => {
    event.currentTarget.classList.toggle('bg-salmon');

    //initialize data
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    let id = (event.currentTarget.id);
    console.log(id);

    axios.post('http://localhost:80/project-api/readActiveDoctor.php',userId )
    .then((res)=>{
      //set data to response
      setData(res.data)
    //   setActiveVet(renderActiveVet);
    //   setRenderActiveVet(false);
  
    })
    .catch(err=>{
      console.log(err);
    });

    return (
        <div className="div">
            {data && data.map((item, index)=>{
                return <DoctorInfo key={index} rerender={setRenderActiveVet} uniqueId={item.id} name={item.name} surname={item.surname} specialization={item.specialization} age={item.age} gender={item.gender} email={item.email} contact={item.phoneNumber} doctorId={item.doctorId} room={item.room} />;
            })}
        </div>
    );

}

// second component --destructure props--
export const DoctorInfo = ({ name, surname, specialization, ...etc })=>{
    return (
        <div>
          
             <button  onClick={showVetInfo}  className='individual-vet' id={uniqueId}   >
                     <div className='vet-block-img'>  <img className='profileImg vet' src={dp}/></div>
                     <div className='vet-block-text'>
                         <h2>Dr. {name + " " + surname}</h2>
                         <h4>{specialization}</h4>
                     </div>
                </button>
            
        </div>
    );
}
```